# Sniff socket activity of the current process in Windows & .Net

Tags: .net, windows, sockets, hook

I'm trying to analyze a .Net remoting-based library.  I'm using [SocketSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html) currently as a separate process to count the total socket sends and receives of all the operations (for this process) combined but it is very monotonous to manually get figures for individual operations (setting/hitting breakpoints, tally new activity, repeat).

**Is there a way to hook into or sniff socket activity in-process in Windows & .Net (possibly with the right P/Invoke)?**  I just want to track how many packets are sent/received as they happen and then, optionally/eventually, timings of each and I guess byte counts.

This code below seems to work correctly (requires administrator privileges), but it captures all traffic from all processes (right?).  How might I reliably limit the captures to only those sent to or received from the current process without making any assumptions about the ports or protocols?  Maybe that additional criteria requires a wholly different approach.

I tried calling `GetTcpTable2()` with each received packet and looking for the local address and port combination associated with my `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id`.  That seems to bring back some but not all results - probably because the Socket is closed and cleaned up most of the time before I'm able to parse through to the TCP header and call `GetTcpTable2()`!  Then I tried capturing the list of `GetTcpTable2()` IPEndpoints just before `wrote = mainSocket.EndReceive(r)` and that also doesn't give all the results I expect to see.

```
static async Task CaptureSocketActivity(IPAddress localAddress, CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        var mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw,
                                ProtocolType.IP);

        mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localAddress, 0));

        mainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,
                                    SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded,
                                    true);

        byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
        byte[] byOut = new byte[4];

        mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut);

        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
            {
                int wrote = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[mainSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];

                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                        (cb, s) => mainSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, mainSocket.ReceiveBufferSize, SocketFlags.None, cb, s),
                        r => wrote = mainSocket.EndReceive(r),
                        null);

                    bw.Write(buffer, 0, wrote);

                    if (wrote < mainSocket.ReceiveBufferSize) break;
                };

                bw.Flush();

                Console.WriteLine($"Saw a raw IP packet of {ms.Length} bytes.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're packet sniffing, then you're going to need to know ports and addresses to identify the packets you're interested in. If you want to inspect what a process is doing you're going to want a debugger, just like you'd use if you wanted to see what a processes was doing to memory. Another option might be to use a proxy and tell the process to connect to the proxy, then use the proxy to inspect traffic flowing through it.

Comment: Yes that's a way, but I intend to collect these results from multiple users' machines automatically rather than interactively.  SocketSniff seems to be able to do it (an no install required).